# How will data size get affected on csv to mysql import

Tags: mysql, csv

How will the data size comparison be when we go for csv file to mysql import ? Will it be proportional or an increase ?

Comment: Could you explain why this matters to you?  A CSV flat file is a very different beast from a table in a MySQL database.

Comment: What sort of data is the file? Strings/ints? How large is the CSV file?

Comment: @GrishaLevit. Eg) the csv file is as large as 10gb with string data.

Comment: It's likely impossible to know without trying.  Depends on the database backend used, any compression settings enabled and how compressible the data is, how many empty cells there were in the CSV, etc.  You'd be best off just trying an import and seeing what you end up with.